# Why Kotlin type inference does not work for functional interface?

Tags: kotlin, http4k

I'm working on a [http4k](https://www.http4k.org/) web app. Http4k has a nice [functional scheme](https://www.http4k.org/guide/modules/core/) for http handlers and filters (aka interceptors).

```kotlin
typealias HttpHandler = (Request) -> Response

interface Filter : (HttpHandler) -> HttpHandler {...}
```

I wanted to write a simple filter so I created a function which **returns a `Filter`**

```kotlin
fun throwNotFoundResponses(): Filter {
    return { next: HttpHandler ->
        { request: Request ->
            val response = next(request)
            if (response.status == Status.NOT_FOUND) {
                throw NotFoundException()
            }
            response
        }
    }
}

// example usage
Filter.NoOp
        .then(throwNotFoundResponses())
        .then(routes(...))
```

However Kotlin complains (Line number edited to match the example above.)

```
NotFoundThrower.kt: (2, 12): Type mismatch: inferred type is (HttpHandler /* = (Request) -> Response */) -> (Request) -> Response but Filter was expected
```

Why Kotlin cannot infer the types are actually identical?

Comment: `Filter` extends `(HttpHandler) -> HttpHandler`, it's not identical to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Filter is an interface that extends `(HttpHandler) -> HttpHandler`, so it is a subclass of it, not a superclass.

Maybe it's easier to see if you don't have functional syntax.

```
open class Animal
class Kitten: Animal()

fun doSomething(): Kitten {
    // You cannot return an explicit Animal here, even though the Kitten implementation
    // has not defined any unique members or overridden anything. 
}
```

Your lambda is literally a `(HttpHandler) -> HttpHandler` and cannot be inferred to be a Filter any more than an arbitrary Animal could be cast to a Kitten. It doesn't matter that we didn't happen to add any functions to Kitten or override anything. It's mere declaration means it is a distinct subtype and the compiler will never assume otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filter()` ~constructor~ overloaded operator function `invoke` and provide filter function to it:

```
fun throwNotFoundResponses(): Filter {
    return Filter { next: HttpHandler ->
        { request: Request ->
            val response = next(request)
            if (response.status == Status.NOT_FOUND) {
                throw NotFoundException()
            }
            response
        }
    }
}
```

or more concise:

```
fun throwNotFoundResponses(): Filter = Filter { next: HttpHandler ->
    { request: Request ->
        next(request).takeIf { it.status != Status.NOT_FOUND } 
            ?: throw NotFoundException()
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter is an interface, it doesn't have a constructor

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko it is interface and it obviously doesn't have constructor, that's correct. But it has invoke [operator overloaded there](https://github.com/http4k/http4k/blob/master/http4k-core/src/main/kotlin/org/http4k/core/Http4k.kt#L9)

Comment: @ruX Yes thanks. That's what I initially did. However my question is not "How to make this work?" but "Why Kotlin cannot infer that the types are actually identical?"

From the comment above I assume that the problem here is that `Filter` has the overloaded invoke operator and the types are in fact not identical. Right?

It that's true and if you rephrase your answer to address my original question in the first place I will accept it. .)